# Getting the triangles of a mesh from its vertices

Tags: collision

I am having trouble implementing the Polygon-Soup Collision detection on this page. I have implemented the methods presented in that paper but I am not sure how to get the values for the CollisionPacket class. Can anyone help me in getting the values for the CollisionPacket class?

**EDIT:** I have implemented that, but how can get the triangles of the mesh from its vertices for the *checkTriangle()* method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was to obtain the vertex positions while loading the .obj files and store it in the RawModel class in my game. Thanks for any help.